# Spring context file : Properties file outside jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties

I know this question has been asked multiple times , but I am not able to get solution for my particular case. here is what I am trying - 1) I am trying to load properties file placed outside jar in my context file using tag
 `<context:property-placeholder location="file:classpath*:config/myConfig.properties" />`

And this my folder structure -

`/opt/data/code/myapp.jar
/opt/data/code/lib/*.jar - all 3 rd party dependencies
/home/mano/security/config/myConfig.properties`

Then I am using java command to run this app - command being executed from `/opt/data/code` directory

`java -cp /opt/data/code/lib/*:/home/mano/security/:/opt/data/code/myapp.jar com.App`

And its not finding the properties file and I see logs like these -

[main:support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver@631] **Looking for matching resources in directory tree [/opt/data/code]**
[main:support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver@693] **Searching directory [[/opt/data/code] for files matching pattern [/[/opt/data/code/classpath*:config/myConfig.properties]**
[main:support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver@424] Resolved location pattern **[file:classpath*:config/ddConfig.properties]** to resources []

Why is it not looking in complete classpath directories instead looking into path from where java command was executed.